# What Azure storage feature to use for image posts?

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to create an app in Xamarin.Forms which can store photos and their description and names. In this app, there will be users and image loading will depends on account with what you signed in. I store images in storage accounts and its urls I store in Azure Easy Tables. 
I want to ask that for saving names and descriptions I should use Azure Easy Tables or other Azure storage feature ? If I should use Easy Tables how can I load only specific data for specific user?

Thanks for your answers !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you are using Azure Mobile Apps for your mobile app backend. You could leverage Azure Mobile Apps server SDK to store related data which is stored under blob storage / file shares.

> I want to ask that for saving names and descriptions I should use Azure Easy Tables or other Azure storage feature ? If I should use Easy Tables how can I load only specific data for specific user?

Azure Mobile Apps support two backend languages (C#,Node.js). For C# backend, you could follow the tutorials below to implement your requirement.

**C# backend & Xamarin.Forms projects**

[App Service Mobile sample todo list client app with images](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-todo-list-files)

[Connect to Azure Storage in your Xamarin.Forms app](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-blob-storage.md)

Easy Tables are served by Node.js backend. For Node.js backend, Azure Mobile Apps have not provided the similar File Management server SDK as C# backend. Details, you could follow [30 DAYS OF AZURE MOBILE APPS](https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/).

For associating data with the specific user, you could follow adrian hall's book about [Data Projection and Queries](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/projection/) for C# backend, [30 DAYS OF ZUMO.V2 (AZURE MOBILE APPS): DAY 6 – PERSONAL TABLES](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-6-personal-tables/) for Node.js backend.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you very much !